# Regex Zero or More Spaces Within a Group of Digits

Tags: regex

suppose I have a sequence of one to three digits that can have any number of spaces in between them, and suppose that these numbers are within a group that I can back reference. How would I go by doing this? Here's what I have so far

```
([\d\s*]{1,3})
```

I'm just a bit confused as to how I'm to have a pattern that matches up to three digits, have zero or more spaces between then, and keep them within a group.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: The pattern `[\d\s*]` matches ONE digit OR one space OR one literal `*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
((?:\d\s*){1,3})
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/yl2uiM/1)

---

Explanation:

```
((?:\d\s*)){1,3}
  ^      ^        define a non capturing group
     ^            a single digit
       ^          a space zero or more times
^         ^       capture that group (digit and following space pattern)
           ^      1 to 3 times
```

You can also do:

```
 ^(\d\s*\d?\s*\d?\s*)
  ^                 ^     capture group
    ^                     one digit
      ^                   zero or more spaces
         ^                optional digit
            ^             zero or more spaces
               ^  ^       etcetera.....
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/fkoktD/1)

Comment: Can you go over how this works?
It does do what I need, I just want to understand how it does it as I'm a bit new to regex's. Also, is there a way to do this without using the colon?

Comment: Yes. The `(\d)` is one character.  `\b(w+)\b` is a word-like group of characters.

Answer (score 0):

`(\d{1,3}\s*)` should get you what you want, I think.  That defines a group comprised of 1-3 digits, and any space that appears before the next group of digits.  If you didn't want to include the space in the group, you could use `(\d{1,3})\s*`

Comment: 'suppose I have a sequence of one to three digits that can have *any number of spaces in between them*'  -- this only matches 1 to 3 digits followed by any number of spaces. Not spaces between.